# java RESTful webservice + DAO + JDBC best practice

Tags: java, web-services

My goal it to build a RESTful webservice to CRUD data into Oracle and MySQL databases.

Could you please provide some best practices for RESTful webservice to CRUD database ?

1. Do I need use DAO or implement directly the JDBC directly in the webservice classes ? If could provide some useful links with example will be helpful.
2. I use the connection pool ! Does it's OK or ... ?
3. Where/how to keep some configuration values, such as database connection string, database credentials, etc ? Does the it OK to use config.properties file for all this ? Something like that:

   config.properties
   db_url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/
   database=test
   db_user=my_user
   db_password=my_password

   InputStream input = new FileInputStream(config.properties);
   Properties prop = new Properties();
   prop.load(input);
4. To CRUD the database I'm planning to use PreparedStatement. What you recomand: to use SQL statements (select * from ..., update ... set, delete ...) directly in java code or build some some stored procedures to query, insert, update, delete the data ?
5. I want that application will be able to work with different databases. I want start with MySQL and Oracle. What are best practices to implement such approach ? Use DAO ? How to keep the configuration to different type of databases ?

Here is some code that I started:

```
package com.crunchify.restjersey;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/testws")
public class TestWS {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String currentDate() {
        Date dt = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        return df.format(dt);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getTables")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTables() {
        return "Noroc";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getConnection")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getConnection() {

        String result = "";
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
            Context environmentContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            String dataResourceName = "jdbc/MySQLDB_db";
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) environmentContext.lookup(dataResourceName);
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();

            if (!conn.isClosed())
                result += "Connection established!";
            else
                result += "Cannot establish connection!";



            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            result += ex.getMessage();
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you prefer to use standard JEE techniques like JAX-RS on some sort of Application server (since you look up your Datasource via JNDI).

1. I would recommend using DAOs for DB-Access. DAOs typically reduce boilerplate code like obtaining DB connections, mapping Query results to POJOS etc. Furthermore I would recommend to use some sort of O/R mapper for your DB-Access. JPA and "plain" Hibernate are the most common ones (for JPA use the implementation your App server provides or Hibernate on Tomcat).
2. Yes, you should definitely use a connection pool.
3. Where to keep configuration values is somewhat environment specific. Generally the configuration should not be packaged within your artifact (WAR, JAR, EAR) unless there is some mechanism to override your configuration values. Common options are Java-System-Properties and Command Line Arguments.
4. As stated above I would recommend to use some O/R mapper. If using plain SQL, prepared statements are a good idea. Prepared statements make sure, you are not vulnerable to SQL-Injection-Attacks which may occur if you put some unescaped user input as parameter in your SQL-statement.
5. Again I would recommend to use an O/R mapper (JPA or Hibernate). The configuration depends on your environment. You will configure a Datasource on an application server like Jboss/Glassfish/Websphere. Other environments will use configuration files, java system properties or environment variables.

For your task personally i would use spring boot since it is relatively easy to get started. Relevant guides are:

- http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ for REST-Services
- http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ for JPA

That said similarily good options would be JEE (JAX-RS, JPA) on an application server of your choice or Dropwizard.

Btw. further aspects to look at later on are validation, authentication and authorization, transaction management etc.